# How to enable copy-eliding move members for Eigen vectors?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, eigen, copy-elision

The **move** support for **Eigen** [was submitted in this patch in 2011](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=266#c1). However I cannot find the move constructor in the Matrix header file. Also the Eigen webpage still has move semantics listed as a ["to do"](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Todo) item. All this indicates that the patch has not yet been submitted to a release version

This test program proves that the move constructor leaves the **moved object unchanged**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
    Eigen::VectorXd first = Eigen::VectorXd::Constant(3, 3.14);
    std::cout << "first\n" << first << std::endl << std::endl;
    Eigen::VectorXd other = std::move(first);
    std::cout << "first\n" << first << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "other\n" << other << std::endl << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
first
3.14
3.14
3.14

first
3.14
3.14
3.14

other
3.14
3.14
3.14
```

How can I enable the copy eliding move functionality from the above-mentioned patch in **Eigen 3.2.0.**?

**EDIT:**

It seems that there is nothing wrong with the move semantics of the Eigen classes. However there are only **default** move constructors and move assignment operators.

The patch providing **explicit** move constructors and move assignment operators, which avoid copying the entire data has not yet been merged into a release version.

I would like to know:

1. How to apply this patch to Eigen 3.2.0? Is there a tool or should I just modify the  files by hand.
2. Does anyone have experience using this patch?

Comment: Why would you think that? How do you imagine "moving" would look like?

Comment: I would expect `first` to be empty after being moved to `other`

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: For a start, that's not what moving means.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: Second, what's an "empty vector"?

Comment: @KerrekSB By empty I mean having `first.size() == 0`

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: What if the vector has small-buffer optimizations? Would you expect it to put in extra work to reset the size?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you think that the feature is "finished": though a patch was submitted, that bug is clearly still open which, along with your experience, suggests the patch has not been merged into the Eigen source tree.

You also have a bug in your testcase: you appear to be expecting `first` to be "empty" in some way after the move, but it will instead be in an unspecified state. Though it does appear from a quick glance at that patch submission that one might expect the "empty" result in practice, there is not sufficient context within the patch to really know what state the moved-from object will be in. So, unless you have some other source of information, your expectation is somewhat ill-founded.